# Hibernate JPA composite key

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

[image: Entity Relationship]

I am very new to Java and JPA/hibernate.
For the above described table structure I have the following Entities created.

Table1:

```
@Entity
public class Table1 implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="work_item_no")
private String workItemNo;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="tcTcr", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Table2> table2;
```

Table2:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Table2")
public class Table2 implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="errtrack_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long errtrackId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="work_item_no")
private Table1 table1;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="table2", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Table3 table3;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="table2", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Table4> table4s = new ArrayList<Table4>();
```

Table3:

```
@Entity
public class Table3 implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="errtrack_id")
private long errtrackId;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="errtrack_id")
@MapsId
private Table2 table2;
```

Table4:

```
    @Entity
@IdClass( Table4PK.class )
public class Table4 implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="errtrack_id")
private long errtrackId;

@Id
@Column(name="line_item_no")
private int lineItemNo;


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="errtrack_id",referencedColumnName ="errtrack_id")
@MapsId
private Table2 table2;
```

Table4PK:

```
    public class Table4PK implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(name="errtrack_id")
private long errtrackId;

@Column(name="line_item_no")
private int lineItemNo;
```

I save Table1 using JpaRepository.save.

```
 Table1 table1 = trans.GetTable1();
List<Table2> tb2Arr = new ArrayList<Table2>();

for (Task task : request.getTasks()) {
    Table2 table2 = trans.GetTable2(task);
    table2.setTable1(table1);

    Table3 table3 = trans.GetTable3());
    table2.setTable3(table3);
    table3.setTable2(table2);

    int index = 0;
    for (Trade trade : table2.getTable4s()) {
        index++;
        Table4 table4 = trans.GetTable4(trade, index);
        table4.setTable2(table2);
        table2.getTable4s().add(table4);
    }

    tb2Arr.add(table2);
}
```

table1.setTable2s(tb2Arr);
Table1 savedTable1 = table1Repo.save(table1);

I have everything working until Table3. But Table4 is not getting saved because the autogenerated value is not getting populated.

Table4 has composite key and one field in the compiste key is a foriegn_key from another table.

Error:

```
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 547, SQLState: 23000
2018-06-27 02:01:15.453 ERROR 15512 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint...
```

In the profiler I see that, generated `errtrack_id` from Table2 is not populated on Table4.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. - Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the exception you are getting and the code of your service for storing the data?

Comment: added the service code for save and exception details